# Monitoring of pending transactions

Tags: web3.py, pending-transactions, txpool

I'm using Web3.py with Infura

Is it possible to see in real time the last pending transactions ?
And have all the informations about it like who send it, who received it and more.

The idea is to do a specific action when a specific transaction is seen in the mempool

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. Just be aware that some transactions might be mined pretty quickly and they will skip pending pool and directly appear in a block. Also network latency contributes to that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is possible. Web3.py has this already implemented nicely.

```
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://provider.com"))
w3.geth.txpool.content()
```

This gets you the dictionary containig `queued` and `pending` transactions.

```
    {
'pending': {
    '0x0216d5032f356960cd3749c31ab34eeff21b3395': {
    806: [{
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x0216d5032f356960cd3749c31ab34eeff21b3395",
        'gas': "0x5208",
        'gasPrice': "0xba43b7400",
        'hash': "0xaf953a2d01f55cfe080c0c94150a60105e8ac3d51153058a1f03dd239dd08586",
        'input': "0x",
        'nonce': "0x326",
        'to': "0x7f69a91a3cf4be60020fb58b893b7cbb65376db8",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0x19a99f0cf456000"
    }]
    },
    '0x24d407e5a0b506e1cb2fae163100b5de01f5193c': {
    34: [{
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x24d407e5a0b506e1cb2fae163100b5de01f5193c",
        'gas': "0x44c72",
        'gasPrice': "0x4a817c800",
        'hash': "0xb5b8b853af32226755a65ba0602f7ed0e8be2211516153b75e9ed640a7d359fe",
        'input': "0xb61d27f600000000000000000000000024d407e5a0b506e1cb2fae163100b5de01f5193c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053444835ec580000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'nonce': "0x22",
        'to': "0x7320785200f74861b69c49e4ab32399a71b34f1a",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0x0"
    }]
    }
},
'queued': {
    '0x976a3fc5d6f7d259ebfb4cc2ae75115475e9867c': {
    3: [{
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x976a3fc5d6f7d259ebfb4cc2ae75115475e9867c",
        'gas': "0x15f90",
        'gasPrice': "0x4a817c800",
        'hash': "0x57b30c59fc39a50e1cba90e3099286dfa5aaf60294a629240b5bbec6e2e66576",
        'input': "0x",
        'nonce': "0x3",
        'to': "0x346fb27de7e7370008f5da379f74dd49f5f2f80f",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0x1f161421c8e0000"
    }]
    },
    '0x9b11bf0459b0c4b2f87f8cebca4cfc26f294b63a': {
    2: [{
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x9b11bf0459b0c4b2f87f8cebca4cfc26f294b63a",
        'gas': "0x15f90",
        'gasPrice': "0xba43b7400",
        'hash': "0x3a3c0698552eec2455ed3190eac3996feccc806970a4a056106deaf6ceb1e5e3",
        'input': "0x",
        'nonce': "0x2",
        'to': "0x24a461f25ee6a318bdef7f33de634a67bb67ac9d",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0xebec21ee1da40000"
    }],
    6: [{
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x9b11bf0459b0c4b2f87f8cebca4cfc26f294b63a",
        'gas': "0x15f90",
        'gasPrice': "0x4a817c800",
        'hash': "0xbbcd1e45eae3b859203a04be7d6e1d7b03b222ec1d66dfcc8011dd39794b147e",
        'input': "0x",
        'nonce': "0x6",
        'to': "0x6368f3f8c2b42435d6c136757382e4a59436a681",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0xf9a951af55470000"
    }, {
        'blockHash': "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        'blockNumber': None,
        'from': "0x9b11bf0459b0c4b2f87f8cebca4cfc26f294b63a",
        'gas': "0x15f90",
        'gasPrice': "0x4a817c800",
        'hash': "0x60803251d43f072904dc3a2d6a084701cd35b4985790baaf8a8f76696041b272",
        'input': "0x",
        'nonce': "0x6",
        'to': "0x8db7b4e0ecb095fbd01dffa62010801296a9ac78",
        'transactionIndex': None,
        'value': "0xebe866f5f0a06000"
    }],
    }
}
}
```

Docs: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.geth.html?highlight=txpool#web3.geth.txpool.TxPool.content

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 way of doing that, check it out in Quicknode's blog:
https://www.quicknode.com/guides/defi/how-to-access-ethereum-mempool
Get txpool.content is usually quite slow as you have to fetch and wait all content, then remove the duplicated ones.
Best way is to build your own node, modify the code of geth and filter the transaction in node side.